# integral equality restricted to a measurable set

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f_{n}$ be positive measurable functions that converge pointwise to $f$ and such that $ \int f = \lim \int f_{n} < \infty$  Prove that for any measurable set $E$, we have $ \int f = \lim \int f_{n}$ if both integrals are taken over the set $E$.

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: Hint: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem

Comment: No, there's no assumption that these are dominated by an integrable function.

Comment: @Martin: The dominated convergence theorem is not good enough, as Robert points out. You need to generalize it slightly using Fatou since you don't have a dominating function.

Comment: @t.b. I thought that I can take $f$ as the dominating function in this special case. (The post contains and assumption $\int_X f = \lim_X \int f_{n} < \infty$, which means that $f$ is integrable; at least that how I understood it.)

Comment: @Martin: but you don't know that $f_n \leq f$.

Comment: @t.b. Ok, I understand. (I should not have missed that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: try using [Fatou's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma#Standard_statement_of_Fatou.27s_lemma).

Comment: got that thank you.

but what is the relevance of the less than infinity? is there a counter example where the integral is equal to infinity?

Comment: @alice: Take your favourite example of positive $f_n$ converging pointwise to $f$ on, say, $[0,1]$ with $\lim \int_0^1 f_n(x)\ dx \ne\int_0^1 f(x)\ dx$, and take $f_n(x) = f(x) = 1$ on $[1,\infty)$.  Let $E = [0,1]$.